# How to save the elements of a list using HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website where the user can add items to a To Do list. It is possible to add items and also delete them, i did that using JavaScript. But now I want to save the current items of the list when the page is refreshed.

I want the To Do list to save the current items, including the ones added by the user, so that when the page is reloaded the list doesn't go back to its initial form but still maintains the items added. I don't know how to do it, any help would be appreciated as I'm currently learning HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

```js
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myUL {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30rem;
    margin-left: 72rem;
    margin-top: 21rem;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
  
#myUL li {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
    background: #eee;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.2s;
  
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
  
#myUL li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
  
#myUL li:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}
  
#myUL li.checked {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
  
#myUL li.checked::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    top: 10px;
    left: 16px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
}
  
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
  
.close:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}
  
.to-do-header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30rem;
    margin-top: 13.5rem;
    margin-left: 72rem;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    background-color: #9fa77f;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
  
.to-do-header:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.table-title {
    margin-bottom: 0.6rem;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
  
#myInput {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
}
  
.addBtn {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    width: 25%;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    color: #555;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 0;
}
  
.addBtn:hover {
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="to-do-header">
    <h2 class="table-title">To Do</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="What do you want to do?">
    <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
  </div>
  
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li>Wake up</li>
    <li>Meeting with the team</li>
    <li>Have an amazing lunch</li>
    <li>Finsish the project</li>
    <li>Get some pizza</li>
    <li>Go to sleep</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I'd start with something simple like [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (except you'll lose that if they use a different browser or clear cache etc) or you'll need to have your own database of sorts and graduate to a contemporary framework or library on top like Angular or React (to make life easier) etc. Except that's a topic that can go on ad nauseam, so the question is pretty broad unfortunately.

Comment: @ChrisW. I am aware of the advantages of using frameworks such as Angular or React. But for this project I want to keep it simple, so I'm just looking for a basic javascript solution as the website is for personal use, it's just me exploring the use of javascript with html and css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested, the simplest approach is to store the list contents as a string in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You would update the string in `localStorage` any time the list is altered and when the page initially loads, you'd check `localStorage` to see if there is a list there to restore.

Now, beyond this, you have several other lines of code that "work", but are not considered the modern approach to coding.

- [Do not use `.getElementsByClassName()` or `.getElementsByTagName()`
  in just about all use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474). Instead, use `.querySelectorAll()`,
  which by the way returns a node list that can be iterated over using
  [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), so there's no need for traditional loops that rely in
  indexes.
- [Don't use inline HTML event attributes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) Instead, separate your HTML
  and your JavaScript and do event handling in JavaScript.
- No need to explicitly create a text node (`createTextNode`) and
  append it to the element to whom the text node should become a child
  of when you can just set the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property of the element
  and be done.

**Keep in mind that the following snippet won't work here at Stack Overflow due to sandboxing, but it will work on a real page [as shown in this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2zfws6e/12/).** So go to the Fiddle and alter the list in some way. Then, close your browser and go back to the Fiddle. You'll see your latest list is restored.

See comments in ALL CAPS below:

```js
// WHEN THE PAGE IS READY FOR INTERACTION, CHECK TO SEE IF
// A LIST IS PRESENT IN LOCALSTORAGE AND, IF SO, RESTORE IT.
const theList = document.querySelector("#myUL");
let ls = localStorage.getItem("list");
if(ls){
  myUL.innerHTML = ls; // Restore the list from localStorage
}

// DO YOUR EVENT BIDNING IN JAVASCRIPT, NOT WITH HTML EVENT ATTRIBUTES LIKE ONCLICK
document.querySelector("span.addBtn").addEventListener("click", newElement);


// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
// >>>> DON'T USE GETELEMENTSBYTAGNAME as it an old legacy API
// >>>> USE QUERYSELECTORALL WHICH ALLOWS FOR FOREACH LOOPING
document.querySelectorAll("LI").forEach(function(element){
  const span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  span.classList.add("close");
  span.textContent = "\u00D7";
  element.appendChild(span);
});

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
const close = document.querySelectorAll(".close");
close.forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // YOU SHOULD BE REMOVING THE ELEMENT NOT JUST HIDING IT
    this.parentElement.remove();
    // UPDATE LOCAL STORAGE 
    localStorage.setItem("list", myUL.innerHTML);
  });
});

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
});  //  >>> THE SECOND ARGUMENT (FALSE) IS THE DEFAULT

const theInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  // NO NEED TO EXPLICITLY CREATE A TEXT NODE AND THEN APPEND IT.
  // JUST SET THE TEXTCONTENT PROPERTY AND BE DONE.
  if (theInput.value === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    li.textContent = theInput.value;
    theList.appendChild(li);
    // UPDATE LOCAL STORAGE 
    localStorage.setItem("list", myUL.innerHTML);
  }
  theInput.value = "";

  const span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  span.classList.add("close");
  span.textContent = "\u00D7";
  li.appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
/* Avoid inline styles just add/remove the following
   class when something needs to be hidden/shown  */
.hidden { display:none; }

#myUL {
    position: absolute;
    width: 32rem;
    margin-left: 10rem;
    margin-top: 24rem;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
  
#myUL li {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
    background: #eee;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.2s;
  
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
  
#myUL li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
  
#myUL li:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}
  
#myUL li.checked {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
  
#myUL li.checked::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    top: 10px;
    left: 16px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
}
  
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
  
.close:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}
  
.to-do-header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30rem;
    margin-top: 13.5rem;
    margin-left: 10rem; 
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    background-color: #9fa77f;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
  
.to-do-header:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.table-title {
    margin-bottom: 0.6rem;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
  
#myInput {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
}
  
.addBtn {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    width: 25%;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    color: #555;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 0;
}
  
.addBtn:hover {
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="to-do-header">
  <h2 class="table-title">To Do</h2>
  <input id="myInput" placeholder="What do you want to do?">
  <span class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>
  
<ul id="myUL">
  <li>Wake up</li>
  <li>Meeting with the team</li>
  <li>Have an amazing lunch</li>
  <li>Finsish the project</li>
  <li>Get some pizza</li>
  <li>Go to sleep</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not interested to use your(any) backend, you could definitely utilize `localStorage`.

Source: [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Basic example:

```
const tasks = [{id:1,title:'save the world', description:'today'},...]

localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks)); // save the tasks

const savedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks')) || []; // load the tasks
```

Comment: Because the OP is talking about saving a `ul` element (which is already a string), `JSON.stringify()` is not needed here.

Comment: I used a generic example just in case he would like to use anything besides a string, but you are right, no need to stringify a string